# Object-oriented way to add modifier to object in blender

Tags: blender

When I add a modifier to an object, the info panel shows `bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='X')`, which assumes I have already selected an object. What's the object-oriented way to do it without `bpy.ops` assuming I have a reference to an object that is not necessarily selected? Does something like `obj.add_modifier` exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the list of modifiers of an object via the `modifiers` attribute:

`obj.modifiers.new(name="wireframe", type="WIREFRAME")`